# Delete elements from Hashmap while iterating over it

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrentmodification

Here is my code. I have an arraylist of visited elements. So I want delete these visited elements from the hashmap and below is code. It gives me concurrentmodification exception.

```
private static void removeVisitedNodes(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Iterator<String> it = arrayList.iterator();
    String temp;
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        temp = it.next();
        System.out.println("temp is " + temp);
        Iterator<Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>> iter = neighbours_reachability_map.entrySet().iterator();

        // iterate through the hashmap to remove elements
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry = iter.next();
            if(entry.getValue().contains(temp)){
                //System.out.println("Contains it"  + entry.getValue().toString());
                entry.getValue().remove(temp);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I checked up a few other similar questions but they did not help much. Is there a neater way to do this without causing an exception? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Works for me can you show us your input values and a stacktrace?

Comment: My neighbours_reachability_mapKey is -                                                           Key : 1 - [4, 5, 6]
Key : 2 - [5, 6, 4]
Key : 3 - [7, 4].. And the list is [4,5] So I am trying to remove all the 4s and 5s from the hashmap. The error is - Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
 at acn.project.testAppend.removeVisitedNodes(testAppend.java:79)
 at acn.project.testAppend.main(testAppend.java:59)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a element whilst in the middle of iterating, use [`Iterator.remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--).

Answer (score 2):

you can put the elementos you want to delete in another collection object and then, after finished the iteration, delete those elements